# ember.js - How to setup a route with an optional ID for lookup, and fallback default model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to setup a route that can take an optional ID to lookup a model to use, while still supporting a default model if one isn't passed in?

eg:

```
   /home/
   /order/
   /order/123
   /order/123/shipping
   /someotherroute/
```

Is there a clean way to do this without using query string params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an index route as your default order, and have a sub resource to hold your specified order.

```
this.resource('order', function(){
  // this.route('index'); this is given to you as a freebie, put your default order in here
  this.resource('specified', {path: ':id'});
})
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't default to this initially. Could you navigate laterally from order/index to order/specified with the same model? (I'm sure I could do a controllerFor check on the index route.)

Comment: You can use a link-to and send in the model from the index, or transitionTo/transitionToRoute and send the model from the index route if you need.